# Aceptar X-CSRFTOKEN XAMPP Django

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, django, xampp

Buenas:

Estoy intentando conectar una aplicación en Django con un servicio en PHP con un xampp como servidor. Estoy enviandole los datos desde una View en Django con un:

```
return redirect('enlace',{'parametros':parametros})
```

Esto me genera esta cabecera:

```
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
es-MX,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-Headers x-csrftoken,x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method GET
Connection keep-alive
Host localhost
Origin http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

El caso es que al redirigir al servicio de Apache me devuelve este error:

```
Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide 
leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost/pruebas/prueba.php (razón: token 
'x-csrftoken' no presente en la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 
del canal CORS prevuelo).
```

Comment: Hola es un problema de Token CRSF, sino un problema de [CORS](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=cors&rlz=1C1RLNS_esAR737AR738&oq=cors&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.1199j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  Por razones de seguridad, los exploradores restringen las solicitudes HTTP de origen cruzado iniciadas dentro de un script. Por ejemplo, XMLHttpRequest y la API Fetch siguen la política de mismo-origen. Ésto significa que una aplicación que utilice esas APIs XMLHttpRequest sólo puede hacer solicitudes HTTP a su propio dominio a menos que se utilicen encabezados CORS.

Comment: Sí, eso lo entiendo pero si es un error de token csrf ya que el mensaje está diciendo que la razón es el token. lo que estoy haciendo es un return redirect('direccion',{'parametros':parametros}) en una de las view y eso manda esta cabecera: Accept 
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
es-MX,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-Headers 
x-csrftoken,x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method 
GET
Connection 
keep-alive
Host 
localhost
Origin 
http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: el servidor de apache está configurado para que acepte los origenes